# pyspark read json which has same field as string and proper json struct and parse value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json like below

```
{
"student": {
            "names": ["aaaa","bbbb"],
            "section": ["one", "two"],
            "running": true
    },

    "code": "001"
}

{
    "student": "{\"name\":\"aaaa\"}",
    "code": "002"
}

{
    "student": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "code": "003"
}
```

I read using below line

df = sqlContext.read.json("file:////home/test/data/info.txt")

when I printed schema it showing as like below

```
root
|-- code: string (nullable = true)
|-- student: string (nullable = true)
```

it printed student as string, but I want student field as json struct

How to convert this student field to json struct, I am okay even if below values gets discarded
**"student": "{\"name\":\"aaaa\"}" and "student": "aaaaaaaaaaa"**

I can not assign the schema while reading json, as I don't know the number of field inside student fields.